# Is the latest Tor-0.2.5.10 Expert Bundle broken?

Tags: configuration, windows, help

I downloaded the latest Tor Expert Bundle [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) for Windows 7 and extracted the files and directory structure of the .zip to `G:\tor-0.2.5.10`. In case it matters, my extracted Tor directory structure is as follows:

```
G:\TOR-0.2.5.10
├───Data
│   │   cached-certs
│   │   cached-microdesc-consensus
│   │   cached-microdescs.new
│   │   lock
│   │   state
│   │
│   └───Tor
│           geoip
│           geoip6
│
└───Tor
        libeay32.dll
        libevent-2-0-5.dll
        libevent_core-2-0-5.dll
        libevent_extra-2-0-5.dll
        libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
        libssp-0.dll
        ssleay32.dll
        tor.exe
        torrc
        zlib1.dll
```

Afterwards, I open up an admin privileged `cmd` into `G:\tor-0.2.5.10\Tor`. But when I run `tor.exe` nothing happens. I see the `tor.exe` process in taskmgr but there is no console logging displayed -- it's almost like the `tor.exe` process started itself as a background fork because right after I run it it brings me right back to the command prompt again.

Running `tor.exe --version` or `tor.exe --help` also doesn't show anything. I did not have any of these problems with an older version of tor. Is this a new issue introduced with the latest version?

**Edit:** For completeness, here's also my `torrc` file in case it's important:

```
DataDirectory ../Data
#ControlPort 9151
SocksPort 9150
# UseBridges 1
# bridge 60.16.182.53:9001
# bridge 87.237.118.139:444
# bridge 60.63.97.221:443
# ExitNodes 172.10.0.0/16
GeoIPFile ../Data/Tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File ../Data/Tor/geoip6
MaxCircuitDirtiness 1800
ExitNodes {ca},{gb},{au},{us}
StrictNodes 1
```

Comment: It does start itself as an immediate background process. This is a known bug, not just for the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13819), due to the lack of developers working on the Expert bundle.

Meanwhile, if you are looking for a workaround, you can use Tor binaries and files found in  the TorBrowserBundle. You will find `Tor/` and `Data/` directories under **c:\*path-to-your-torbrowser-dir*\TorBrowser\Browser**. The rest should be easy. And you will get a console output with this version.

Comment: Linostar's answer pointed me in the right direction and allowed me to find a workaround. To get `tor.exe` to print logging information I need to pipe it to `more` like so: tor.exe -f torrc | more Some caveats: to quit I have to kill `tor.exe` through taskmgr, <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> does not work, and I have to manually scroll the logged output whenever a page is full. While not ideal it does provide a workable solution for the time being at least until the tor maintainers fix the issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Like advised I found the Tor binary inside the Browser bundle. I ran it using cmd. I did tor -h. Nothing happened. No error. How do I use this?

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, running `tor.exe | more` gives you console output of tor

Answer (score 0):

Tor expert bundle is primarily for people who use Internet Explorer or an alternate browser, also, you must manually configure it as follows:

- extract the files in a new directory (name it whatever you want)
- Create a shortcut to the Tor.exe file on your desktop
- Open Internet Explorer and go to Tools-Internet Options-Connections, then open the Lan Settings tab
- Uncheck Auto detect settings and check "use proxy for Lan connection"
- Click advanced button, and setup ONLY the SOCKS with 127.0.0.1 , port 9050
- Save and close
- Click the Tor.exe shortcut on your desktop (it will open in the background)
- Open Internet Explorer, and Tor will work.

Comment: "expert bundle is primarily for people who use Internet Explorer" - as long as it is hard to imagine such an expert using Tor with IE, I assume the basic idea of Tor developers was about those non-techies sitting on IE could accommodate expert bundle, right?

Comment: P.S. And yes, I do expect some expert still might come here and report that "he's happily and securely uses IE", well just to prove the point.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install tor as NT service https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#NTService

For you

> G:\TOR-0.2.5.10\Tor\tor.exe --service install -options -f G:/TOR-0.2.5.10/Tor/torrc