# Tor expert bundle on Windows - no installation instructions

Tags: configuration, windows, directory

Before there was a installer.

Now it's just a zip file with no installation instructions.

Where do I put the DATA directory?

Also when I run tor.exe nothing happens, I see no command line options or anything

Comment: The expert bundle assumes you're familiar with Tor's configuration options, one of which is datadir. Sounds like you should read up on that.

Comment: Writing an instruction would be helpful, since Vidalia is dead these days, and there is no way to run Tor except directly, from Expert Bundle or via the Tor Browser. Or providing a BAT/CMD file to install Tor as a Windows Service would be useful too.

Answer (score 6):

It's running in the background. For console output, add `| more` to the end.

Like this:

```
tor --hash-password "Password" | more
```

I recommend new users to go with `Vidalia` from [here](https://people.torproject.org/~erinn/vidalia-standalone-bundles/)

Comment: Note, that Vidalia is no longer supported by Tor developers and the last update at the pointed location is of Dec 2013. So, no joy for non-techies who do like their choice of browser.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `tor.exe` file in your zip file. Clicking on it may seem to do nothing, but actually it will run under a hidden window. This is a [known bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13819).

See  [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6199/7159) for a workaround.