# Add bridges on expert bundle

Tags: configuration, windows, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, obfs4

I want to add bridges to my expert bundle but have no idea how to create and what to put in the torrc file.

First of all, there is no torrc file in the expert bundle, so I assume I have to create it (give me an example of what it should include). I want to use an obfs4 transport.

I usually use the expert bundle without being able to see its logs and statuses (it just runs on the background). If there is a solution to this please let me know.

I know that using the expert bundle might no be good, but I need it for a few applications so please try helping me before you lecture me about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: You may find and answer here : https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/3757

Answer (score 1):

> Give me an example of what it should include:

This is an example `torrc` file:

```
DataDirectory C:\Documents and Settings\ron\Desktop\Tor\Data
#ControlPort 9151
SocksPort 9150
# UseBridges 1
# bridge 60.16.182.53:9001
# bridge 87.237.118.139:444
# bridge 60.63.97.221:443
# ExitNodes 172.10.0.0/16
GeoIPFile C:\Documents and Settings\ron\Desktop\Tor\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Documents and Settings\ron\Desktop\Tor\Data\Tor\geoip6
MaxCircuitDirtiness 1800
ExitNodes {ca},{gb},{au},{us}
StrictNodes 1
```

You can place the `torrc` file in the `Data\Tor` but you can keep it anywhere you like and specify the location using the `-f` option when invoking the process.  directory.

Expert bundle doesn't come with Pluggabletransport, so you have to get it separately. There used to be a Pluggabletransport bundle for Windows, but do not know [what happened to it](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/tor-pluggable-transports-browser-2.4.11-alpha-2_en-US.exe). Looks like the best option is to [get it](https://silvenga.com/openvpn-obfuscating/) from TBB.
As an example, you can add the following to your `torrc` file:

```
## obfs4proxy configuration
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec Path\To\obfs4proxy
```

To see the output of `tor.exe` refer to other [posts](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/is-the-latest-tor-0-2-5-10-expert-bundle-broken/6199#6199) in this site. In addition, this [tutorial](https://roastedonion.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/upgrading-your-bridge-to-an-obfsproxy-bridge/) posted by a user in his blog might also be helpful.

Comment: A problem! Bridge **must** be with a key, so no MitM attack attempt will pass undetected. `bridge <ip>:<port> <key>`