# Validate torrc file

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I recently changed my `torrc` file. How do I validate whether I did it right? As in, is there any way to test whether `torrc` configurations work as intended?

I'd hoped TorCheck would provide such functionality eventually, but I can understand it's a security risk to be able to read `torrc` from the Tor browser itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--verify-config` flag. (See the [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) for more options.)

However, you have to pass the flag to the Tor executable itself, rather than the `start-tor-browser` script, which is probably what you're used to using to get things running.

The executable is in the `tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/` directory. The complete command to run on Linux would be:

`tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor --verify-config`

The Windows equivalent would be:

`.\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe --verify-config | more`

Note that the `| more` is required in Windows to workaround a [bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13819) that prevents console logs being output. (See this thread for more details: [Is the latest Tor-0.2.5.10 Expert Bundle broken?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/is-the-latest-tor-0-2-5-10-expert-bundle-broken/6199#6199).)